# Sorted array from two lists

Tags: python

I am trying to solve the following question and can't seem to find what the problem with my code is:

You are given an array of strings names, and an array heights that consists of distinct positive integers. Both arrays are of length n.

For each index i, names[i] and heights[i] denote the name and height of the ith person.

Return names sorted in descending order by the people's heights.

Here is my code

```
    def sortPeople(self, names: List[str], heights: List[int]) -> List[str]:
            res=[];
            while len(heights)!=0:
                res.append(names[heights.index(max(heights))]);
                names.remove(names[heights.index(max(heights))])
                heights.remove(max(heights));
            return res
```

Comment: *What* problem? Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

how about this?

```py
>>> names=['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> heights=[10, 5, 7]
>>> [name for _, name in sorted(zip(heights,names), reverse=True)]
['a', 'c', 'b']
>>>
```